# What road hubs models or manufacturers use replaceable cartridge/sealed bearings?

Tags: hub, bearings

whilst opinions differ on which is better, cartridge bearings (aka sealed bearings) vs loose-ball bearings. I'm attracted cartridge bearings based hubs, because of the prospect of just periodically replacing these cheap seemingly standard bearings to maintain my hub.

Which manufacturers and/or hub models make make use of standard cartridge bearings? (As opposed to highly custom bearings that could only be bought from the manufacturer)

[image]

Comment: Something tells me most of cartridge bearing hubs are serviceable and almost any decent manufacturer has such a product in their lineup.

Comment: Bearing balls are standard items and cones very common spare parts. I think you are exaggerating the difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe approach this the other way around. Identify the wheels you like (one or more model) and as part of your purchase decision, see how easy it is to source replacement bearings.

If there are many and varied places to get the bearings from, not limited to cycling retailers, then you know getting replacements will likely be straightforward. You’ll have done the best you can for now.

6903 RS is a bearing size I’ve seen often enough.

I haven’t got to the heart of the question of course, I also would still be interested if other people know whether there is anything like an industry standard right now.

Update: one resource is a poster produced by Elvedes of the aftermarket bearings they produce.
https://elvedes.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Elvedes-Poster-v4_web.compressed.pdf
Maybe not exhaustive or guaranteed for the future, but could prove helpful.

Comment: Other brands are of course available but the poster lists the names and dimensions of typical size cartridges

Answer (score 0):

(i will update this list as i find more..)

- Fulcrum Racing 7
- Fulcrum Racing 5
- Campagnolo VENTO / KHAMSIN / SCIROCCO

Comment: You’re going to find plenty, I believe Shimano are the major manufacturer that makes a point of still using cup and cones. If that’s even still true. But if you get to the point where you’ve compiled a list of popular wheels and the cartridge sizes they use then you might create a good resource! Note that hub/bearing dimensions for thruaxles are potentially a pitfall as models could have different older or even current variants

Comment: haha ok. i'm just trying to find entry level road wheelset with replaceable standard bearings!!

Comment: At the entry level it’s likely that the cartridge sizes will be quite widely available aftermarket when they need replacing. Economically minded manufacturers will specify common sizes. I don’t know if you’ll find a ‘standard’ but interested to know